# Speeding up prime number finding algorithm for large numbers

Tags: python

My code for [Project Euler problem 7](https://projecteuler.net/problem=7) seems correct because it works for small numbers, but it takes forever for large numbers. Where did I go wrong

```
prime_numbers = []
for number in (range(2,2000000000)):
    if number > 1:
        for i in range(2, number):
            if number % i == 0:
                break
        else:
            prime_numbers.append(number)
print(prime_numbers[10001])
```

Comment: What error message do you get for large numbers?

Comment: What do you mean by large number? Which number is large? How large works? How large doesn't work?

Comment: if the range is above 1 million

Comment: I don't get an error message, I just get nothing

Comment: Probably works fine. Your loop is just taking forever. Note that any even number will not be prime. That will cut your loop iterations in half, and `range(2` will guarantee `number > 1`, so that is not needed... And there are faster ways to compute primes than modulo

Comment: Project Eulers's exercises are carefully elaborated so that you learn to think on more efficient algorithms as you go. What you have there is the simplest "brute force" way of checking prime numbers, and there are several optimizations you couls and should use there. Again: the problems are elaborated in a way to take you away from brute-force, and rethink your algorithms.

Comment: To be clear: you approach needs calculations that get more intensive with the square of the size of the number you are checking. Since you check it for all numbers stating from 2, it goes with the cube of the series size you are checking.  If you simply skip the even numbers you'd need 1/4 of the calculations, for example

Answer (score 1):

Look at comments and other answers for inspiration on using a faster algorithm. This answer suggests some small speed optimizations to your algorithm, which may be enough to get the result in time.

1. Stop as soon as you have your result:

   ```
   prime_numbers = []
   number = 1
   while True:
       number += 1
       for i in range(2, number):
           if number % i == 0:
               break
       else:
           prime_numbers.append(number)
           if len(prime_numbers) > 10001:
               break
   print(prime_numbers[10001])
   ```
2. No need to look at even numbers or divisors:

   ```
   prime_numbers = [2]
   number = 1
   while True:
       number += 2
       for i in range(2, number, 2):
           if number % i == 0:
               break
       else:
           prime_numbers.append(number)
           if len(prime_numbers) > 10001:
               break
   print(prime_numbers[10001])
   ```
3. The upper limit of i can be lower: the square root of number:

   ```
   import math
   prime_numbers = [2]
   number = 1
   while True:
       number += 2
       for i in range(2, math.isqrt(number) + 1, 2):
           if number % i == 0:
               break
       else:
           prime_numbers.append(number)
           if len(prime_numbers) > 10001:
               break
   print(prime_numbers[10001])
   ```
4. Only look at prime divisors:

   ```
   import math
   prime_numbers = [2]
   number = 1
   while True:
       number += 2
       divisor_limit = math.isqrt(number)
       no_divisor = True
       for d in prime_numbers:
           if d > divisor_limit:
               break
           if number % d == 0:
               no_divisor = False
               break
       if no_divisor:
           prime_numbers.append(number)
           if len(prime_numbers) > 10001:
               break
   print(prime_numbers[10001])
   ```

Comment: Another optimization: Only check `number % i == 0` with previously calculated primes because we only care about prime factors.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi: Added your optimization as step #4.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is valid, but not very fast - and therefore for large numbers, your program is just going to take far too long. You could try to make some changes, skip even numbers, don't range from 2 to the number but rather 2 to the square root and so on, but you could also look at a different, faster approach called the Sieve of Eratosthenes, you can read about it [here](https://cp-algorithms.com/algebra/sieve-of-eratosthenes.html).